# Resources in apk cannot be overlay

Tags: android

I am using the RRO function, and after installing the replacement apk, I call the apk's resource using getApplicationResource, and cannot use the latest drawable.
If I restart the device, I can call the latest alternative drawable.

[aobout RRO](https://source.android.google.cn/docs/core/architecture/rros?hl=zh-cn#static-rros)

I'm pretty sure my resources have been replaced
[image]

Is it related to the cache of resource?